# how to create a tikzset style for a rectangle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create a rectangle of width 0.2 and height 0.3 cm. I also want it to be filled with blue color.

How can I do such a style so that I can specify just the name of style, position and label for every rectangle?

for a circle I m using  -

```
\tikzset{user/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=0.6cm, fill=red!60, draw=none}}
\node[user] at (2,6) {$A$};
```

Also How can I do it for other shapes? I mean can somebody point me to a resource so that I can find all the the options for various shapes?

Comment: Perhaps just looking in the pgfmanual section 48 Shape Library _could_ help...

Comment: The same way you uses for circle is available for rectangle: `\tikzset{myrectangle/.style={inner sep=0pt, minimum width=0.2cm, minimum height=0.3cm, fill=blue, draw=none}}`. All nodes have a default rectangular shape. For other shapes read manual's `shapes library` section.

Comment: Since the question is answered by Ignasi's comment and answered in depth in the TikZ manual, I suggest to close this question, since answers doesn't add value to the documentation in the manual.